# Looking for similar instances MS-excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large number of lists of courses that I go through manually to check that the courses have separate start dates and that they do not have overlapping courses.

I´ll give an example below
Column A contains the program's name ex watchmaker training.
Column B contains the course name eg. Watchmaking 1 in cell B1,
watchmaking 2 in cell B2 etc.
Column C contains the start date of the courses
Column D contains the end date of the course.

What I want to do is check if there are instances where courses that have the same name but different number ex. Clock maker 1 and watchmaking 2 have the same start date.
Edit:
Here is a link to an example of how it looks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn25N.jpg

what I'm looking for is instances like ones that are marked with yellow.
Where the name in column 2 is almost the same except for the number.
So i would like to check of the courses have overlapping times.

Is this even possible to do in excel? 
Also sorry for my bad spelling since english isn't my first language

Comment: Yes, it can be done with `SUMPRODUCT`. Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1425808/edit) to include sample data and the expected outcome.? it would be useful to help provide a more detailed answer

Comment: You say you have “Watchmaking 1” in cell `B1` and “watchmaking 2” (or “Watchmaking 2”?) in cell `B2`.  (So you have no header row?)  And so I guess `A1` contains “watchmaker training” or “Watchmaker Training”.  What’s in ``A2``?

Comment: You mean to say that you want to highlight Row has Same **Programme Name and Start Date** ?

Comment: @Rajesh S exactly, or somehow note if there’s a program with the same name but different number that are scheduled under the same time period eg. programme 1 starts 2019-01-01  and ends 2019-01-31 and programme 2 starts 2019-01-10 and ends 2019-01-31. So basically I want to check if the course programme levels 1 and 2 are scheduled during the same time period.

Answer (score 0):

**Conditional Formatting will solve your issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select required Data Range.
- On **Home Tab** reach to **Conditional format** 
  then **New Rule**.
- Enter this Formula,

  `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$A1,$B$2:$B$7,$B2)>1`
- Click **Format button**, apply an appropriate 
  Color/Pattern, finish with **Ok**.

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*